# проблема создания элементов в HTML через JS, если подгружать модули

Tags: javascript, html

через JS элементы, но если в начале скрипта подключить какой-либо модуль, то уже ничего не работает. что делать?!

```
var fs = require('fs'); /* Если убрать эту строку, то все работает*/

var cardBack=document.createElement('img');
```

В консоли ошибка: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Comment: так уберите эту строчку :) Вроде она для NodeJS

Comment: В браузере не было, нет и никогда не появится ни функции require, ни тем более прямого доступа к файловой системе

Comment: тогда следующий вопрос, если я уберу эту строку, то как мне загрузить в массив имена файлов в папке, который буду использовать в дальнейшем на сайте?

Comment: @Илья, никак...

Comment: Не забывайте, что весь javascript выполняется в браузере пользователя, а к файлам вашего сайта на вашем сервере вы можете получить доступ каким-нибудь обыкновенным php-скриптом или типа того (или даже через тот же NodeJS)